# not pass my json arrays to php, I dont know why

Tags: ajax, json, simple-html-dom

My code is not working in browser, and not send datas to process.php. I don't know where is the problem.

My original js data structure - data-today.php (which daily updated and I open after the head)

```
var football = new Array(); football[0] = new Array('Argentina','Primera Division','Boca Juniors'); football[1] = new Array('Argentina','Primera Division','Lanús'); football[2] = new Array('England','Premier League','Arsenal'); football[3] = new Array('England','Premier League','Liverpool');
```

And here is my code, and I would like to pass all datas to a simple html dom parser. I don't know where is the problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js">
</script>
<script src="data-today.php" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--






$(document).ready(function () {

        var json = JSON.stringify(football);
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {



alert(json);
$.ajax ({
  type:"POST",
  url:"process.php",
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
  async: true,
  data: {
         country: $("json[i][0]"),
         competition: $("json[i][1]"),
         team: $("json[i][2]")},
  success: function(){ alert("data")},
  error: function(){ alert("error")}
});
            }
    });







</script>


<table>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("json[i][0]")` will literally parse `$("json[i][0]")`.

Comment: and what does it mean?

Comment: if `var football` is an array, why are you using `JSON.stringify()` and then trying to access it as an array in `json[i][0]`?

Comment: I already tried with var json = football;  but the result is the same

Comment: I still don't know where is the problem in my code :(

Comment: @Liverpool: that means that it will literally search for all the html tags `<json[i][0]>`, which is not exactly what you want to do. In a nutshell, your "json[i][0]" is NOT resolving neither [i] nor [0], because it is inside a **string** and, in javascript, you have to concatenate. The correct format is just json[i][0] without the "", but it won't work in any case because the logic behind this is wrong, that is the main problem. Also, you should queue your ajax requests, which is important!

Comment: Are you sure that it is is not working.  Since you are setting contentType to `application/json`, you will need to read POSTed data from PHP raw input rather than `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the data already nicely in javascript array and if you really want to post the data in the for loop you can use something like below.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    // scrap that line, you have the values in array (of arrays)
    //var json = JSON.stringify(football);

    for (var i = 0; i < football.length; i++) 
    {
        //alert(json);
        $.ajax ({
          type:"POST",
          url:"process.php",
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: "json",
          async: true,
          data: {
             country: football[i][0],
             competition: football[i][1],
             team: football[i][2],
          success: function(){ alert("data")},
          error: function(){ alert("error")}
        });
     }
});
```

You probably should also rename your data-today.php to data-today.js as it seems to be a javascript file instead of php one...

Answer (score 0):

(1) `var football` is an array, so when you do `var json = JSON.stringify(football);` it turns it into a string, so when you do `for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {` it is looping over the string chars, and not an array.

(2) if `json` is an array, then there is no need to make it an object - `$("json[i][0]")`. just access it directly - `json[i][0]`.

So now your code should look like

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var football = new Array(); 
football[0] = new Array('Argentina','Primera Division','Boca Juniors'); 
football[1] = new Array('Argentina','Primera Division','Lanús'); 
football[2] = new Array('England','Premier League','Arsenal'); 
football[3] = new Array('England','Premier League','Liverpool');

$(document).ready(function () {

    var json = football;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"process.php",
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: "json",
          async: true,
          data: {
              country: json[i][0],
              competition: json[i][1],
              team: json[i][2]},
          success: function(){ alert("data")},
          error: function(){ alert("error")}
        });
    }
});

</script>
```

jsFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/pdrw4r73/1/ (I commented out the `alert("error")` in `error: function(){ alert("error")}`, but you can expand the `POST` in the Firebug Lite to see the `$.ajax()` posts.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers for everybody. If I try to update my code I got this error at firefox console: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' , somwhere before the `</script>` tag. I tried both version, but the result is the same if I try to open my process.php.

my process.php:

```
    <?php
include ("auto3.php");
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: I updated my code, but at process.php I got empty arrays as result: Array
(
)

Comment: If I enabled the alert error at the end, then I got simple error message in the popup window